# Ubuntu won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, busybox, superblock

My laptop ran out of power and when I went to plug it in and power it on, Ubuntu no longer boots. I get directed to BusyBox built in shell that looks exactly like:

```
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help'for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

When I type in `exit`, the following output is dumped:

```
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
/init: line 355: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
_
```

I've had a look at [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/) article to see if it could help me out, which prompted me to `dumpe2fs /dev/sda2 | grep superblock`which dumped the following output:

```
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock
```

How can I boot my Ubuntu based OS again?

Comment: You probably have a disk problem and need to troubleshoot that with a bootable disk... get an unbuntu live iso and burn it to a usb disk and boot on it to troubleshoot your disk... also have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519745 there are some useful infos there

Answer (score 0):

Resolved on 22.05.19

I've looked into [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-to-fix-boot-into-initramfs-prompt-and-mount-cant-read-etc-fstab-no-su) question that my post was marked as a possible duplicated and it did not help my cause.

I managed to fix the issue following these steps and resources:

1. My disk was encrypted so after I decrypted it, I was encountering an error while trying to mount it: `mount: unknown file system type LVM2_member`
2. I followed [this](https://www.svennd.be/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2_member/) link to understand how to mount an LVM partition
3. Upon following the above link, I was still encountering issues stating that I had `Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open 
   Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock
4. I then stumbled across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036761/cant-read-superblock-on-dev-mapper-veracrypt1) article which lead me to `sudo mke2fs -n <device>`
5. Then, using one of the options that were output, I ran `sudo e2fsck -b  <one of the displayed options> <device>`
6. The `e2fsck` terminal went crazy at this point and spat out loads of numbers to the terminal for a few minutes. After it was finished, I restarted my machine and was able to gain access to my OS again.

So the issue is resolved but I'm still at a loss in regards to what actually happened.

Comment: It sounds like your file system got corrupted because your laptop was in the middle of an important write. Instead of just fixing it you completely erased the file system and proceeded to recover lost files. You should probably reinstall the OS if your system act weirdly in the future.